# Displaying inherited methods in rdoc

Tags: ruby, documentation, rdoc

I have a program written in Ruby that uses multiple levels of inheritance.  All of the parent classes have implemented methods that an object of a child class would use, but when I generate an rdoc for my program, the rdoc page for a child class only shows the methods for that specific class and no methods from the parent class.

Does anyone know how to display inherited class methods in rdoc?  I have looked through rdoc documentation and some websites and haven't been able to find an answer on whether this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, but I am not aware of any solution. In fact, when I read Rdoc, I've come to learn that I need to click the link that points to the parent class if I'm going to see all the methods that the class supports.