# Create a Hash from two arrays of different sizes and iterate until none of the keys are empty

Tags: ruby

Having two arrays of different sizes, I'd like to get the `longer` array as keys and the `shorter` one as values. However, I don't want any keys to remain empty, so that is why I need to keep iterating on the `shorter` array until all keys have a value.

**EDIT:** I want to keep array longer intact, but without empty values, that means keep iterating on shorter until all keys have a value.

```
longer  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
shorter = ['a', 'b', 'c']

Hash[longer.zip(shorter)]
#=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>nil, 5=>nil, 6=>nil, 7=>nil}
```

**Expected Result**

```
#=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"a", 5=>"b", 6=>"c", 7=>"a"}
```

Comment: Post your expected result.

Comment: `longer.each_with_object({}).with_index { |(x,hsh),i| hsh[x] = shorter[i % shorter.size] }
 #=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"a", 5=>"b", 6=>"c", 7=>"a"} `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an elegant one. You can "loop" the short array

```
longer  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
shorter = ['a', 'b', 'c']

longer.zip(shorter.cycle).to_h # => {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"a", 5=>"b", 6=>"c", 7=>"a"}
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: lots of stackoverflowing :)

Comment: Neat !! Didn't know about cycle at all :O

Comment: I am seeing all these answers and realizing, that i'd also start thinking of some `each_with_object`/`inject` stuff.. meeh learn learn and learn again

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: `each_with_object` is my go-to tool. it's the swiss army knife of enumerable processing :)

Comment: The de-facto official Ruby documentation unfortunately does not show methods from included modules, so the gems in [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) are often overlooked when working with arrays. Same for `Numeric < Integer < Fixnum`.

Comment: @Stefan: well yes, that is logical behavior. It does list Enumerable in "included modules", though.

Comment: Flawless Victory !.  Thank you Serio.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the documentation generated by YARD is much better in that regard: http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array

Comment: @Stefan: indeed, it is! I wonder, is it a special case for Array or do they flatten included modules for all classes?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it seem to be an [RDoc limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1651959/477037).

Comment: Sergio, you don't need to say, "Here's an elegant one". Everybody knows all your answers are elegant.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: oh, stop it, you :)

Answer (score 1):

A crude way until you find something more elegant: 
Slice the longer array as per length of shorter one, and iterate over it to re-map the values.

```
mapped = longer.each_slice(shorter.length).to_a.map do |slice|
           Hash[slice.zip(shorter)]
         end
=> [{1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"}, {4=>"a", 5=>"b", 6=>"c"}, {7=>"a"}]
```

Merge all hashes withing the mapped array into a single hash

```
final = mapped.reduce Hash.new, :merge
=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"a", 5=>"b", 6=>"c", 7=>"a"}
```

Comment: Well, I'll just leave this here for an alternate (longer) approach. Sergio's answer is the best way to achieve this though.

Comment: You were at least the first to understand the OP's intentions.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 ;) Thanks for noticing that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun answer.

```
longer  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
shorter = ['a', 'b', 'c']

h = Hash.new do |h,k|
  idx = longer.index(k)
  idx ? shorter[idx % shorter.size] : nil
end
  #=> {}

h[1] #=> a
h[2] #=> b
h[3] #=> c
h[4] #=> a
h[5] #=> b
h[6] #=> c
h[7] #=> a
h[8] #=> nil

h #=> {}

h.values_at(3,5) #=> ["c", "b"]
```

If this is not good enough (e.g., if you wish to use `Hash` methods such as `keys`, `key?`, `merge`, `to_a` and so on), you could create the associated hash quite easily:

```
longer.each { |n| h[n] = h[n] }
h #=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"a", 5=>"b", 6=>"c", 7=>"a"}
```